# Return string content from onAuthorization CustomAttribute MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authorization, authorize-attribute

I have a custom authorize attribute and i have to sent a string if authorization fails in the result. I want to sent string in the Result as

> filterContext.Result = "Some String Here";

So, that the ajax will read and do something about it.

```
public class PermissionAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{

    public override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (!isAuthorized(user, controllerName, actionName))
                    {
                        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
                        {
                            //I want to retur here string content like.
                            filterContext.Result = "UnauthorizedAccess";
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            filterContext.Result = new ViewResult() { ViewName = "_Unauthorized" };
                        }
                    }
    }

    //function for checking if the user is authorized to access the page 
    private bool isAuthorized(string username, string controller, string action)
    {
        bool authorized = false;
        return authorized;
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried throwing a NotAuthorizedException?  With a message